# Как показывать ошибку 404 вместо редиректа на главную в мультисайтовом Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multilanguage

Есть сайт на WP, когда включаешь мультисайт (используется для мультиязычности), то на главном сайте (site.com) при вводе в адресную строку не правильного урла идет переход на главную страницу, при этом на других языках (site.com/ru) показывает ошибку 404.
Единственное решение, которое нашел заключалось в том, чтобы убрать фильтр:

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'maybe_redirect_404' );
```

Но это не помогло.

Comment: Так не должно быть. Похоже на то, что мультисайт настроен неправильно. Вы изменили настройки nginx при переходе на мультисайт?

Comment: Да, при curl -i site.com/test404 - показывает 301-й редирект на главную, если страница есть, то всё нормально отдается.
Проблема именно для главного сайта, всё остальное работает как и должно.

Answer (score 0):

В .htaccess можно указать куда отправлять пользователя при возникновении ошибки 404

Comment: Это Wordpress, он сам показывает ошибку, когда считает нужным, htaccess тут не при чем, тем более используется nginx.